# Error in installing WINE in 64 bit Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, wine, dependencies

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.8 : Depends: wine1.8-amd64 (= 1:1.8.0-0ubuntu1~ubuntu15.10.1~ppa1) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: wine1.8-i386 (= 1:1.8.0-0ubuntu1~ubuntu15.10.1~ppa1) but it is not installable
           Recommends: gnome-exe-thumbnailer but it is not installable or
                       kde-runtime but it is not installable
           Recommends: fonts-droid but it is not installable
           Recommends: ttf-mscorefonts-installer but it is not installable
           Recommends: fonts-horai-umefont but it is not installable
           Recommends: fonts-unfonts-core but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: ttf-wqy-microhei but it is not installable
           Recommends: winetricks but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: CAN ANYONE TELL ME WHAT IS WRONG WHILE I TRY TO INSTALL WINE1.8 IN UBUNTU 16.04  (64 BIT)

Comment: What is wrong with your Caps Lock?

Comment: @JonnyPaul Ubuntu is case-sensitive. Maybe your capslock is interfering?

Comment: You seem to use a [PPA](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA) version. Is it intentional? Have you tried to install Ubuntu-maintained version? `sudo apt-get install wine`

Comment: Please check this link http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/10/install-wine-stable-1-8-5-ubuntu-16-04-new-ppa/

Comment: It looks like it wants both 64 bit and 32. Try installing 32 but version in the same command to install the 64 bit version

Answer (score 1):

You need to add multiarch support. Its trying to download `wine-i386`

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386 && apt-get update
apt-get install wine
```